# React (Router) Error: "Calling PropTypes Directly is not suppored..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Just started learning React and I'm following a guide to build a basic single page app. I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Failed context type: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use PropTypes.checkPropTypes() to call them. Read more at <**shortened url I was forced to remove**>
in e
```

The url that was pointed to was: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md#difference-from-reactproptypes-dont-call-validator-functions

That "in e" is not a mistake on my part.

I'm also seeing this error but suspect its caused by the other:

```
TypeError: r.props.history is undefined
```

As I'm new to React I don't even know where to begin. I know there were some issues with react-router and PropType validators in earlier versions of react-router (I'm using 4.1.1).

This is my current index.html - the only file in my project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React! React! React!</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.1.1/react-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    var App = React.createClass({
      render: function(){
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
            <ul className="header">
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>Stuff</li>
              <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
            <div className="content">
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })

    var destination = document.querySelector("#container");

    ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactRouter.Router>
        <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>

        </ReactRouter.Route>
      </ReactRouter.Router>,
      destination
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issues is on the way you are calling the Router. 
Since version 4+, `React Router` uses `BrowserRouter`, from the `React Router DOM` package.

Just add `React Router DOM` from the UMD bundle and your code should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React! React! React!</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.1.1/react-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    var ReactRouter = window.ReactRouterDOM
    var App = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
            <ul className="header">
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>Stuff</li>
              <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
            <div className="content">
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })

    var destination = document.querySelector("#container");
    ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactRouter.BrowserRouter>
        <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}/>
      </ReactRouter.BrowserRouter>,
      destination
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Further reference on: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with the `React` version that you are using please use the latest version, the prop-types package has some incompatibility issues please check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types#compatibility), if you are starting learning React I suggest to start with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

schweller, i do not believe both react-router and react-router-dom are needed in this case.  only react-router-dom is necessary.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.1.1/react-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17078747)

Comment: hi @Alisson, i understand that my answer merely clarifies/corrects a previous answer, but due to my lack of reputation i was unable to comment directly on his answer.

i understand if you feel it best to remove my answer given the rules.  thanks!  bill